Convex function $f(x,y) = \lvert xy \rvert + a (x^2 + y^2)$
Show that the function $f(x,y) = \lvert xy \rvert + a (x^2 + y^2)$ is convex if and only if $a \ge 1/2$.
$f$ is not differentiable, right?  If we did not have the absolute value we could differentiate and go with the Hessian criterion. So, you have to go with the definition, which does not lead anywhere with the calculations. Is there some trick I need to apply here?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

first, I don't see any way to edit the question

It might help to note that $\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) + |xy| = \frac{1}{2}(|x| + |y|)^2$.

In the question there is no reference to convexity, only in the title

@TheoBendit I used this information and tried to write f as a composition of vector functions, so I took g(x1,x2) = 1/2(x1^2 + x2^2) + x1*x2, h(x1,x2) = (|x1|,|x2|). But I did not manage to prove that g is non-decreasing for each argument in order to apply the vector composition rule

We can see that $\frac{1}{2}(|x| + |y|)^2$ is a convex function, using the fact that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}x^2$ is increasing and convex on $[0, \infty)$, while $(x, y) \mapsto |x| + |y|$ is convex with range $[0, \infty)$, because it is a norm (or directly, using triangle inequality of $| \cdot |$).
We can also see $x^2 + y^2$ is convex a number of ways, either by sums of convex functions, or by Hessians. As such, if $b \ge 0$, $b(x^2 + y^2)$ is convex as well.
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{2}(|x| + |y|)^2 + b(x^2 + y^2) = |xy| + \left(b + \frac{1}{2}\right)(x^2 + y^2)$$
is convex, proving $f$ is convex when $a \ge \frac{1}{2}$.
We still need to show the converse, i.e. if $f$ convex, then $a \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Fix $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Let
\begin{align*}
v &= (1 + \varepsilon, 1 - \varepsilon) \\
w &= (1 - \varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon).
\end{align*}
Then $\frac{1}{2}(v + w) = (1, 1)$. We have,
\begin{align*}
f(v) &= |1 - \varepsilon^2| + a((1 + \varepsilon)^2 + (1 - \varepsilon)^2) \\
&= 1 - \varepsilon^2 + 2a(1 + \varepsilon^2).
\end{align*}
Similarly,
$$f(w) = 1 - \varepsilon^2 + 2a(1 + \varepsilon^2).$$
Thus,
$$1 + 2a = f(1, 1) \le \frac{1}{2}(f(v) + f(w)) = 1 - \varepsilon^2 + 2a(1 + \varepsilon^2),$$
hence,
$$2a \varepsilon^2 \ge \varepsilon^2 \implies a \ge \frac{1}{2}.$$
Thus, if $f$ is convex, then $a \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Thanks. I did not get the last argument. You show that on the line a has to be a >= -1/2 for f(x,x) to be convex. How do you draw the conclusion for f(x,y) ?

@user2614870 Any convex function will remain convex when restricted to a line. So, if $f$ were convex for $a < 1/2$, then $f(x, x)$ would be convex too. But since it is not convex for $a < 1/2$, $f$ is not convex either. You could also show that$$f(0, 0) > \frac{1}{2}f(1, 1) + \frac{1}{2}f(-1, -1)$$when $a < 1/2$.

So that gives that f is not convex for a < -1/2.  What about when a is on (-1/2, 1/2)

@user2614870 Oh, right, I see the problem. Let me think it over.

https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F16/homework/homework1.pdf
here's the problem statement btw, it's the convex optimization course from CMU

@user2614870 I came up with an alternative.

cool trick, thanks
